# How to call a sub routine of one form from other form?

Tags: vb.net, subroutine

i'm a new in vb.net, i would like to ask if how can I call a sub routine of the main form from another form.

I tried putting the prefix of the main form( main.subroutinename() ), it doesn't show an error when compiled but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You might want to read up on scoping of subroutines, Public/Private etc. This may be too much of beginner level to ask here, I guess. You say that you are calling with main.subroutine. The subroutine, belongs to the form object, it doesn't belong to another subroutine called 'Main'. Even if the subroutine belongs to the form, it should be its public member to be callable from other forms. Even then it would be a bad idea unless you have a strong case for it. Don't be surprised if this question is downvoted for "not doing due prior research". You might want to present a sample of your code.

Comment: It has to be Public Sub, then you do with with Form1.SubName, where Form1 is the instance of your form.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the effort guys, I really appreciate it, yeah sorry i forgot to mention, the subroutine was declared as a public sub and still it doesn't work. Actually i just want to enable the textbox of the main form by clicking a button from another form. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

As Microsoft says:

**Calling syntax**

You invoke a Sub procedure explicitly with a stand-alone calling statement. You cannot call it by using its name in an expression. You must provide values for all arguments that are not optional, and you must enclose the argument list in parentheses. If no arguments are supplied, you can optionally omit the parentheses. The use of the Call keyword is optional but not recommended.

*The syntax for a call to a Sub procedure is as follows:*

```
[Call] SubName[(argumentlist)]
```

***You can call a Sub method from outside the class that defines it. First, you have to use the New keyword to create an instance of the class, or call a method that returns an instance of the class***. For more information, see New Operator. Then, you can use the following syntax to call the Sub method on the instance object:
***Or you can create a `Sub` Routine in a `Module` making it visible (`Friend` or `Public`, etc) then calling it inside entire the `Namespace` that contain your `Module`***

```
object.MethodName[(argumentList)]
```

*Illustration of declaration and call*

The following Sub procedure tells the computer operator which task the application is about to perform, and also displays a time stamp. Instead of duplicating this code at the start of every task, the application just calls tellOperator from various locations. Each call passes a string in the task argument that identifies the task being started.

```
Sub tellOperator(ByVal task As String)
    Dim stamp As Date
    stamp = TimeOfDay()
    MsgBox("Starting " & task & " at " & CStr(stamp))
End Sub
```

The following example shows a typical call to tellOperator.

```
tellOperator("file update")
```